# How to get web context from infopath form?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I have SharePoint form Library, and InfoPath form with 1 text field. My problem is, that i need to get somehow lib. URL of Form Library and set it to the text box f.g

```
string _s = this.aplication.activeForm.GetUrlOfLibrabry();
```

How to get parent lib URL? 
(form is opened in INFOPATH not in browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure for InfoPath 2007, but for 2010 you have the form library URL available in the querystring. I recommend that you do the following:

1. Inside the FormEvents_Loading method get the querystring parameter.

   if (eventArguments.InputParameters.ContainsKey("SaveLocation"))
   {
       var docLib = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(eventArguments.InputParameters["SaveLocation"]);
   }
2. Save the Url in a InfoPath hidden field so you can read it later (_spListUrl in this case).

   // store into xml data

   XPathNavigator navigator= nav.SelectSingleNode("my:myFields/my:_spListUrl", NamespaceManager);
   navigator.SetValue(sDocLib);

I hope this helps

Comment: if (e.InputParameters.ContainsKey("SaveLocation")) is false... strange problem is that InputParameters are empty... e.InputParameters.Count return 0

Comment: Have you checked the URL to see if the parameter is there? The link that is opening the form was built by SP or you?

Here you can check an example: http://www.scottjamison.com/blog/2007/01/office-sharepoint-server-2007-forms-services-querystring-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian, have you tried:

```
this.ServerInfo
```

this will give you lots of methods that you can query (i.e. SharePointListUrl, etc...)

Comment: it's not working. I cannot get this.ServerInfo... i am using infopath 2007. I know how to get template URL, this.Template.Uri, but still i want the url of lib. I dont know why i cant use your code inside FormEvents_Loading(object sender, LoadingEventArgs e) or other, i have references... i read about it, but maybe the problem is 2007 infopath?